# Why this code works in PowerShell but it doesn't change nothing in the html file (with Regex)

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have `file1.html` with this lines:

```
<bogus></bogus>
 <title>Something goes here</title>
 <TheEnd>END</TheEnd>
```

I made 3 different PowerShell scripts with regex in order to change this line:  `<title>Something goes here</title>`:

```
  $path = 'c:\Folder1\file1.html'
  $Content = Get-Content -Path $path
           
  foreach($Line in $Content){
      $Line -replace "<title>(.*?)</title>",'$1 NEW is now there!'  #This regex selects everything between tags and make a replace:
  }
  Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $Line
```

AND

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path c:\Folder1\file1.html  
  
   foreach($Line in $Content){
       $Line -replace "<title>(.*?)</title>",'$1 NEW is now there!'  #This regex selects everything between tags and make a replace:
   }
  Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $Line
```

OR

```
$path = 'c:\Folder1\file1.html'
$Content = Get-Content -Path $path  
$GetTitle = [regex]"<title>(.*?)</title>"
 foreach($Line in $Content){
     $Line -replace $GetTitle,'$1 NEW is now there!'  #This regex selects everything between tags and make a replace:
 }
  Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $Line
```

The output should be.

`<bogus></bogus>`

`<title>NEW is now there!</title>`

`<TheEnd>END</TheEnd>`

Mention that all my codes are working in PowerShell, but does not make any change in `File1.html`. That is the problem. can anyone correct my codes?

Comment: You don't seem to be writing anything back to the file.  Did you try something like `Set-Content` to save your changes?

Comment: yes, i try  with a last line: `Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $Content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex `-replace`, you need to think what you want to keep and capture that in backreferences.
In your case, you want to retain `<title>` and `</title>`, and replace what is in between those tags.

Change the regex to `'(<title>).*?(</title>)'`.

Also, you can use the `-Raw` switch on Get-Content to read the file as a single multilined string, do the replacement and pipe the result straight through to `Set-Content`

```
$path = 'c:\Folder1\file1.html'
(Get-Content -Path $path -Raw) -replace '(<title>).*?(</title>)', '$1NEW is now there!$2' |
    Set-Content -Path $Path
```

Details:

```
'$1' +                     Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1
' NEW is now there!' +     Insert the character string “ NEW is now there!” literally
'$2'                       Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $path = 'c:\Folder1\file1.html'
 $Content = Get-Content -Path $path 
 $newContent =@() 
 $RegexForTitle = '(?<=title>).*(?=</title>)'
 foreach($Line in $Content)
 {
     $newContent += $Line -replace $RegexForTitle,'NEW IS NOW HERE!'
 } 
 Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $newContent

 #optional this line

'| Out-File -path file1.html'
```